# Why does my bed explode when I try to sleep on it in the Nether, and how do I disable it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After I read the changelog for Minecraft 1.6, I saw that one of the few items that were fixed was beds in the nether. However, when trying to sleep in one, it explodes. Is this purely intentional, and does this happen in SMP (can't confirm now)? If it does explode in SMP, can I disable it (the explosion) for beds only, in case some griefer does this?

EDIT: Since it happens in SMP, is there a mod to disable this? Even if the bed kills them (the griefers) they still can go into the portal and wreak havoc in it

Comment: I don't have the answer to your other questions, but the behavior **is** intentional. Why? I have no idea.

Comment: It **does** happen in SMP.

Comment: Why would you bring a bed to the Nether, and why would you sleep in it? There's no night or day there!

Comment: There's a reason there are quotes around “Fixed” in the changelog!

Comment: Beta 1.6.6 fixed the bed behavior further so that you will be killed (more powerful than TNT) upon using it in the nether (you only took minimal damage before 1.6.6).

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[It *is* intentional](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/hiaku/the_changelist_for_16_the_word_of_notch/c1vm5cq?context=1), does happen in SMP, and cannot be disabled on a vanilla server as far as I know. On a Bukkit server, the [DisableIt plugin](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/misc-sec-disableit-disable-some-naturally-occurring-events.27417/) can disable any type of explosion, including beds.

In the Nether, there basically is no time of day — bring a watch with you and see what happens. The beds only let you sleep in them when it's night time, and this lack of time apparently confuses them to the point of spontaneous explosion.

Sleeping in the Nether has never worked, but before Beta 1.6 the beds were neither sentient nor quite as explosive; you'd simply get the "you can only sleep at night" message. Of course, this isn't really appropriate for the Nether, since it is never night. Notch likely wanted to make it more obvious to players that beds don't work in the Nether at all. Why explosions? I'm not sure, but it certainly drives the point home, doesn't it? Possibly [Evil Notch](http://twitter.com/Evil_Notch) had a hand in this.

Comment: +1 for confused inanimate objects spontaneously exploding

Comment: Then can I disable the explosion using a plugin (bukkit)?

Comment: @bckbck You can. I've edited in a link to the NoExplode plugin. There are likely to be more plugins that do this, but NoExplode seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: It also happens in the other "dimension accessed through a portal", the End.

Comment: Note, sleeping is possible, you (first person) just can't do it as a player.  Villagers can sleep just fine in the nether.

Answer (score 5):

The nether is a place of nightmare. You don't want to sleep there. Your bed exploding is the equivalent of the worst dream you could possibly experience.

Answer (score 0):

I did see a link on Minecraftforums page stating they have seen the problem, but in the update they should've resolved it. My suggestion is not to sleep in the nether because theres no day/night cycle, so there is really no point in sleeping there.

Comment: I would assume the point to sleeping there is to reset a spawn, possibly to be near some large nether construction project.

Comment: @PeterLeppert A good way to reset a spawn like this is to build a portal back to the normal world, then put a bed there.

Answer (score 0):

In the same way that it's unsafe to sleep in the outdoors in the normal world, it's unsafe to sleep in the nether. What does the nether have? Ghasts. I always thought the exploing bed was because ghasts *love to blow stuff up*. They just can't help themselves. As there's no dawn in the nether also, you just sleep until one fires an exploding wad of phlegm at you, and **KA-BLOOEY** explodey death time..

Comment: It's not ghasts doing it, it's the bed itself exploding.

Comment: I know that's how the *mechanics* of it works, but I find it easier to believe it's ghasts doing it, rather than beds becoming explosive when going to the nether.